# Changing Z-index of listview selector to be above row views

Tags: android, listview

I have a standard list where the rows contain images and textviews.

I would like to have the ListView's default listSelector to show up at the highest Z-index.  Currently, it shows the animation under/behind the images.  I want it to show the listSelector animation on top of the images and TextView.

Is this possible without creating a dummy ImageView in the row itself?

Comment: Have you tried setting your listview's drawSelectorOnTop attribute to true? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:drawSelectorOnTop

Answer (score 0):

As per freddieptf's comment, the solution is to set "drawSelectorOnTop" to true on the ListView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:drawSelectorOnTop